# Creating file via ansible directly in container

Tags: docker, ssl, ansible, containers

I want to create a file, directly in a container directory.

I created a directory before:

```yaml
   - name: create private in container
     ansible.builtin.file:
      path: playcontainer:/etc/ssl/private/
      state: directory
      mode: 0755
```

But it doesn´t let me create a file in that directory

```yaml
   - name: openssl key
     openssl_privatekey:
      path: playcontainer:/etc/ssl/private/playkey.key
      size: "{{ key_size }}"
      type: "{{ key_type }}"`
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The path you use looks highly bogus and I suspect you thing that using `somecontainername:` prefix will address that container. This is not the case.

Comment: A more robust approach would be to make the credentials available on the host, and bind-mount them into the container when you start it.  It should be very unusual to do work "inside containers".

Answer (score 1):

From scratch full example to interact with a container from ansible.

*Please note that this is not always what you want to do. In this specific case, unless if testing an ansible role for example, the key should be written inside the image at build time when running your Dockerfile, or bind mounted from host at container start. You should not mess with the container filesystem once started on production.*

First we create a container for our test:

```bash
docker run -d --rm --name so_example python:latest sleep infinity
```

Now we need an inventory to target that container (`inventories/default/main.yml`)

```yaml
---
all:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: docker
  hosts:
    so_example:
```

Finally a test `playbook.yml` to achieve your goal:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    key_path: /etc/ssl/private
    key_size: 4096
    key_type: RSA

  tasks:
    - name: Make sure package requirements are met
      apt:
        name: python3-pip
        state: present

    - name: Make sure python requirements are met
      pip:
        name: cryptography
        state: present

    - name: Create private directory
      file:
        path: "{{ key_path }}"
        state: directory
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 0750

    - name: Create a key
      openssl_privatekey:
        path: "{{ key_path }}/playkey.key"
        size: "{{ key_size }}"
        type: "{{ key_type }}"
```

Running the playbook gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/default/ playbook.yml 

PLAY [all] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Make sure package requirements are met] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [so_example]

TASK [Make sure python requirements are met] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [so_example]

TASK [Create private directory] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [so_example]

TASK [Create a key] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [so_example]

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
so_example                 : ok=4    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

We can now check that the file is there

```
$ docker exec so_example ls -l /etc/ssl/private
total 5
-rw------- 1 root root 3243 Sep 15 13:28 playkey.key

$ docker exec so_example head -2 /etc/ssl/private/playkey.key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEA6xrz5kQuXbd59Bq0fqnwJ+dhkcHWCMh4sZO6UNCfodve7JP0
```

Clean-up:

```
docker stop so_example
```